# Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces and surjective linear maps

Tags: vector-spaces

Given a surjective linear map S between two vector spaces U and V of not necessarily the same dimension, can we find a map from T V to U such that TS is the identity on U?
I think that we can construct an identity on V by the axiom of choice, but I am stuggling to find a counterexample...

Comment: Let $V=0$.$\hspace{1cm}$

Comment: Please could you expand?

Comment: I don't follow. You have a surjective linear map $T\colon U\rightarrow V$. Then you are looking for a map $S\colon V\rightarrow U$, which is... the identity on $U$? What does this mean? How is $U$ identified in $V$?

Comment: Sorry I was unclear! I have edited now !

Comment: Ok, so you have a surjective linear map $S\colon U\rightarrow V$, and you are asking if it is possible to find a linear map $T\colon V\rightarrow U$, such that $TS\colon U\rightarrow U$ is the identity?

Answer (score 1):

As a counterexample, you can take $V=\{0\}$, i.e. the vector space consisting only of the $0$-vector, and let $U$ have some positive dimension. Then the map $S:U\rightarrow V$ has to be the trivial map, which sends all vectors $u\in U$ to $0\in V$.

Also, the map $T:V\rightarrow U$ has to be the one which sends $0\in V$ to $0\in U$.

Thus $TS : U\rightarrow U$ sends any element $u\in U$ to $TS(u) = T(S(u)) = T(0) = 0$, so $TS$ is definitely not the identity on $U$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $S:U\to V$ is surjective.

Does there exist $T:V\to U$ such that $TS = I_U$?

If the dimension of $U$ is greater than the dimension of $V$ then it is not going to be possible.

The rank of $T$ will be less than the dimension of $U$

And it is not possible for $TS$ to have rank greater than that the rank of either $T$ or $S.$